# Ideals of $L^1(G)$, Rudin theorem 7.1.2

Tags: group-theory, fourier-analysis, banach-algebras

I have a doubt about the proof of theorem 7.1.2 that appears in the book Fourier Analysis on Groups by Rudin, I will write the first part of the proof below

($G$ is locally compact abelian group)

> **Theorem 7.1.2** Every closed translation-invariant subspace of $L^1(G)$ is an ideal; conversely, every closed ideal in $L^1(G)$ is translation invariant.

**Proof:** For $f, g \in L^1(G)$ and $\phi \in L^\infty (G)$ we have

$$\int_G (f*g) (-x) \phi(x) dx = \int_G g(-y) (f*g) (y) dy, \qquad (1)$$

since each of these expressions is $(f*g*\phi)(0)$.

Suppose $I$ is closed an translation-invariant, $\phi$ annihilates $I$, and $f \in I$. Then $f*\phi = 0$, the right side of $(1)$ is $0$, hence $\phi$ annihilates $f*g$, for every $g \in L^1(G)$. Since this is true for every $\phi$ which annihilates $I$, the Hahn-Banach theorem implies that $f*g \in I$, and so $I$ is an ideal...

The doubt I have is about the Hahn-Banach theorem, why is it concluded that $f*g \in I$ when applying it?

This theorem is applied in a paper on which I am doing a project for my university. I have read the first part of the book and in my functional analysis class I saw some versions of the Hahn-Banach theorem, but I cannot find the connection with this step of the proof.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: $f*g$ belongs to $I$ because it is annihilated by every continuous linear form on the quotient $L^1(G)/I$ (so its image in this quotient is $0$ by Hahn-Banach).

Comment: If $M$ is a closed linear subset of $X$, a Banach space, then $M\neq X$ iff there is $\lambda\in X^*\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\Lambda(M)=\{0\}$.